# jQuery UI: refresh sortable portlet without refreshing entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, jquery-ui-sortable

I am building a site linked to a database whose interface composes of tabs, and portlets within the tabs, all built using jQuery UI.

main.jsp fires up the tabs:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

and a price.jsp file included in main.jsp fires up the portlets:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        distance: 200,
        containment: 'parent',
        items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
        .find( ".portlet-header" )
            .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
            .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
            .end()
        .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
        $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Within price.jsp, in one of the portlets, I have tabular data that a user might want to refresh from time to time as the database records change, **without refreshing any other portlets in that tab**.

So I'd have a button in the portlet that says refresh:

```
<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</button>
```

However, what this does is that it not only refreshes the other portlets, it refreshes the entire page! This is not what I intended.

I think the onclick function should be something like

```
$(this).sortable({update: function(event, ui){ //some code here//} });
```

but I am not too familiar with the jQuery syntax.

Hope someone can help me figure how to change the onclick function of the button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an AJAX request. Take a look at [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
You'll want to return the table's HTML as the response from the script `$.ajax` requests. Then update your table using `$('#tableID').html(response)` within the `success: function(response)` part of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: now that i've tried testing the .html(response) and .load('web.jsp') functions.. one thing is i am able to refresh the page, but any new data updated in the database AFTER the webpage is loaded is not reflected in the tables when i hit refresh. i am using the following code: ' $(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: "DealList.jsp",
        success: function() {
          $('#blotterpg').load('DealList.jsp');
        }
      });
    return false;
    }); ' any idea how to make the tables updated with the data when i hit refresh??

Comment: what is `$('blotterpg')`? Is that the ID of your table?

Comment: no, its the id of a DIV i used to encapsulate the entire body, so that I can fire up the page within that tag. so it goes something like '<body><div id=blotterpg>.....</div></body>'

Comment: So `DealList.jsp` returns the entire page's content or just the table? If it is the entire page's content then you just replace `.load('DealList.jsp')` with `.html(response)`. If it returns only the table, then the answer is what you should be using.

Comment: i think i see the difference now. just a quick question though - what is response? a string? if so, what does it contain? if DealList.jsp is merely a jsp file with no html tags.. i.e. only <%...%> and <jspbean /> tags, what will response be? can you do a system.out.print to pass value to response?

Comment: Response will contain what the server sends to the client. In other words, what you get when you access `DealList.jsp` manually (from the browser's address bar) is what will be contained in `response`. So if `DealList.jsp` outpus nothing, `response will be blank`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just for those who chance upon the second part of this problem (page not updating the latest database records), I managed to fix it.

After much playing around with the codes, I've discovered that this is really an IE problem. IE caches the view of the database when u first open IE and fire up the JSP page. As such, subsequent updates to the database will be reflected when u hit the IE refresh button, but not that using the jquery ajax .load('*.jsp') function. The .load('*.jsp') function basically brings you back to that cached view when you first loaded the JSP page when u opened IE. So unless you closed and reopened IE, the refresh button used to refresh the table data will not give you **records updated after you first fired up the JSP page**.

The work around to this is to put these codes before you script the JSP page:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

or a meta code in the header that reads:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content=0>
```

Now this workaround is only for those who have problems with IE. I've tested it on chrome and the refresh button functions normally with or without the code above. So there you go.